# Problems with bookmarklet for adding CSS to IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have made a bookmarklet to add a custom CSS file to any page. Works fine in FF and in Safari, but i can't make it work in IE9.

Nothing happens in the DOM inspertor, and i get no error... :( I have tried to execute it directly in the console, but same problem there...

Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
(function(d,u){

if(d.createStyleSheet) {
  d.createStyleSheet( u );
} else {
  var styles = "@import url('"+u+"');",
      css=d.createElement('link');
  css.rel='stylesheet';
  css.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);
  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
}

}(document, "\\vmware-host\Shared%20Folders\css.css"))
```

This is the same code as bookmarklet...

```
javascript:(function(d,u){if(d.createStyleSheet){ d.createStyleSheet( u ); }else{var styles = "@import url('"+u+"');",css=d.createElement('link');css.rel='stylesheet';css.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);}}(document, "\\vmware-host\Shared%20Folders\"))
```

*edit* when i put it directly to the URL, it tells me IE9 has modified the page to prevent cross site scripting :/ Any solution? (and it strips away the javascript: part and bing's it :/ )

Comment: Just a guess: use a `style` tag instead of your `link` tag.

Comment: @Ghommey: You mean `css=d.createElement('style'); css.innerHTML="@import url('"+u+"');"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - as suggested by ghommey - If you have issues due to different origins, then IE has tightened security (makes sense since css can do a lot of stuff) and you will need to use a proxy. That said: Have a look at [IE9 Not applying linked style sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363127/ie9-not-applying-linked-style-sheets)

```
(function(d,u){

if(d.createStyleSheet) {
  d.createStyleSheet( u );
} else {
  var css=d.createElement('style');
  css.setAttribute("type","text/css");
  css.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@import url("+u+")"));
  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
}

}(document, "http://server/some.css"))
```

remember to escape backslashes if you are using local files - for example a server path
`\\` needs to be `\\\\`

Comment: there is an error in your code tbere is a ")" missing after `document.createTextNode(etc..` but i corrected it, and it still works in every browser but in IE9.

Comment: strange why is this one working then? http://www.phpied.com/user-stylesheet-in-ie/

Comment: he is loading a local CSS and not one from the net

Comment: in fact i use a local CSS to, sorry for the bad example in my code... the thing is i have problems with the backslashes in the URL to my local file... any idea how i could fix this?

Comment: i was typing "\\vmware-host\Shared%20Folders\css.css" but when i use "\\\\vmware-host\\Shared%20Folders\\css.css" it works like a charm. If you put this in your answer i can give you the right one.

Comment: @Meo: Great! The more information you give, the better we can help :)

Comment: yes i was using the URL in your example, this was working, i figured it out when i used mine again. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: @Meo: Did the other one work too - the one with the link and href?

Comment: the version with the link and import did work, but i have only tried this in IE)

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in IE8 and Firefox, just changed the href definition:

```
(function(d,u ){
    if(d.createStyleSheet) {
        d.createStyleSheet(u);
    }
    else {
        var css = d.createElement('link');
        css.rel = 'stylesheet';
        css.href = u;
        d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
    }
}(document, "test.css"))
```

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(d,u ){ if(d.createStyleSheet) {  d.createStyleSheet(u); } else {  var css = d.createElement('link');  css.rel = 'stylesheet';  css.href = u;  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css); }}(document, "test.css"))
```

Comment: does not work... :( when i enter it in the URL it tells me IE9 has modified the page to prevent corss site scripting :(

Comment: I guess it worked for me since i used a css from the same domain :( sorry.

Comment: its ok thanks for the research... Would love to get a solution to that problem.