# IE9 standard view no load CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have this problem and maybe I'm not the only..

If I test my website on FF, Chrome, Safari, IE7, IE8 is perfect.

On IE9 (standard view) It doesn't load CSS files. If I switch on Compatibilty view it works fine...

How can I show the CSS on the standard view as well?

Thanks

Comment: Can you temporarily put it live and link to it? Without seeing the site, it's unlikely that anybody can help.

Comment: it's too big... impossible do that... but I think that is a common problem.. but I don't find solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE9 is known to reject stylesheets which are not sent using "text/css" MIME type. This is a new security enhancement, but it's catching a few people off guard. Is your CSS file dynamically generated? Make sure its getting passed as 'text/css'.

More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/27/http-406-not-acceptable-php-ie9-standards-mode-accepts-only-text_2f00_css-for-stylesheets.aspx

---

Another try:: It's not just 'text/css' in the doc that needs to be correct, you need to make sure your local IIS is sending it with the proper headers. "*If a style sheet is ignored due to an incorrect MIME-type, your site may fail to render as expected. Text, images, or other features may lack the desired styling. If a style sheet is ignored because it does not bear the correct MIME-type, a notification will be logged in the IE9 F12 Developer Tools console.*"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622939%28VS.85%29.aspx

[IE9 Not applying linked style sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363127/ie9-not-applying-linked-style-sheets)

Comment: Updated my answer for another stab at it. It still might be the MIME type, even if you properly wrote 'text/css'.

Comment: Interestingly this no longer seems to be an issue in IE 10, which means that if your site works in IE 10, be sure to check it in IE 9 also (especially if you have any dynamically generated stylesheets)!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your local web server is running IIS.  If so, just map the .css file extension to the "text/css" MIME type.  Like this...

In IIS v7.x:

1. Click "MIME Types".  You should see a list of file extensions and the associated MIME type.
2. There should be an entry for the ".css" extension with MIME type = "text/css".
3. If not, add it by right-clicking anywhere on the list -> Add... -> type in the ".css" extension and "text/css" MIME type.

In IIS v6:

1. Right-click the server node -> Properties -> "MIME Types...".  You should see a list of file extensions and associated MIME the type.
2. There should be an entry for the ".css" extension with MIME type = "text/css".
3. If not, add it by clicking "New..." -> type in the ".css" extension and the "text/css" MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a typing error in the way you include the stylesheet. Is the URL correct, and is the tag closed properly?

Comment: I know, but that doesn't mean it's valid. Some browsers are more forgiving on typing errors than others. Will you at least check?

Answer (score 0):

We got this kind of problem with a web project, and the trick was to force IE9 to emulate the website/application
as it was IE8.
To avoid to use IE9's compatibilty mode,put into the code this tag

after the  tag like this :

```
< head>
    < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    ...
< /head>
```

be sure to put it as the first tag after `<head>`, if not it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, then I moved my css file to static server(or any other domain) and used the new url.

It worked for me, see if this can solve the problem for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting the encoding at the top of my stylesheet

`@charset "UTF-8";`