# Why is css missing after refreshing on IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, browser-bugs

I am having an issue that is only happening on Browser Mode:IE9.

If I switch Browser Mode to any other browser it works fine.

This is what happens:
When I arrive on the page, the CSS is there and everything looks fine. However if I refresh the CSS goes away and I lose my styling. If I click to anywhere else on my site then the CSS is still there.
This only happens on my site that is hosted locally.

Comment: You either have too many stylesheets or refer to [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226863/ie9-standard-view-no-load-css

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: @dgvid Unfortunately it's not a public site. Currently it is only on my local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like if the css file is loaded from cache when you navigate normally, but fails to load when it has to be reloaded because you refresh the page. This would mean that it has existed before, but now is inaccessible. Did you try opening the css url in browser?

Comment: Well it looks like on the first load it is sending correctly as text/css but any refreshes are sent as text/html which IE9 no longer recognizes as a valid style sheet.


Also, this is on localhost using IISExpress and I have verified that the correct MimeMap is setup on the applicationhost.config.

Comment: Strange thing. Sorry, I don't know IIS enough to find any reason why this should happen.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue, the solution is to remove the following from the `staticContent` section in the `web.config`:

```
  <remove fileExtension=".css" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

For some reason IE9 thinks the mimeType is invalid when the charset=UTF-8.