# Spring MVC : Return CSS

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

My goal is to merge/minify all css files and return the result as String.

Here's my Spring test method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stylesheet.css", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/css")
@ResponseBody
public void css(HttpServletResponse response) {
    File path = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/includes/css/"));

    File[] files = path.listFiles(...);

    for (File file : files) {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();

        is.close();
    }
}
```

This is working with Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not with IE and Opera.

After some checks in the inspectors, the URL `https://host/project/stylesheet.css` is  loading in each browsers. I can see the content but it does not seem to be recognized as `text/css`.

Also, even with `produces = "text/css"`, I can not see the `content-type` http header in all browsers.

**Error log in IE :**

```
CSS ignored because of mime type incompatibility
```

Does anyone know how to correctly do this?

### **Working code :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stylesheet.css", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Void> css(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/css");

    File path = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/includes/css/"));

    File[] files = path.listFiles(...);

    for (File file : files) {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }

    response.flushBuffer();

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226863/ie9-standard-view-no-load-css But I note that your controller is producing `text/css`. The precise version of IE might be important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually using IE11.

Comment: What message converters are you using (what do you have in your `<mvc:message-converters>` section in your bean configuration file)? It might be a content-negotiation problem, with the result being served with the wrong MIME type.

Comment: Can you check headers of generated response. It should contains: Content-Type: text/css

Comment: @Raedwald : I don't have any `<mvc:message-converters>` section actually. But I have set a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. Is there a converter for resources? I'm going to look for it.

Comment: @alexey28 : There's no `content-type` in the http headers response as mentionned.

Comment: You don't need to write in response. Just return your string from controller method. It should not be void, but String.

Comment: I don't want to return String... Streams are better for memory usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to your usage of `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`.

As the API of `HttpServletRequest` states:

> Forces any content in the buffer to be written to the client.  A call
>   to this method automatically commits the response, meaning the status 
>   code and headers will be written.

My assumption would be that Spring attempts to set the `Content-Type` header on the `HttpServletResponse` after the method on your controller has returned. However, because you have committed the response with your call to `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`, it cannot do this.

I would try either:

- Injecting the HttpServletResponse into your controller and setting the header yourself in code ***before*** calling `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`
- Removing your usage of `HttpServletRequest.flushBuffer()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried to do `response.setContentType("text/css");` or `setHeader(...)` and even with content length but it's not working :(. Removing flushBuffer did not work either.

Comment: Actually, I added the `setContentType` before any write and it worked ! Thanks for it!

Comment: This solved my related problem--although I wasn't using flushBuffer(), I was using getInputStream() and IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream()). Something about the way these methods operate was preventing response.setContentType from occurring. Moving response.setContentType above those lines of code solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since you're writing the content directly to the output stream, you don't need to use `@ResponseBody`. You just need to ensure that you set the `Content-Type` response header. Also, it'd be better to return a `ResponseEntity` (rather than void) to indicate to Spring that you're handling the response yourself.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stylesheet.css", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity css(HttpServletResponse response) {

    // Set the content-type
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/css");

    File path = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/includes/css/"));

    File[] files = path.listFiles(...);

    for (File file : files) {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }

    response.flushBuffer();

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer! Rob Blake got the answer a little before so I have accepted his answer, sorry. BUT, thanks for your helpful tips! I used `@ResponseBody` to test only (it was not there when I wrote the first method). I have understood the issue : we need to specify `Content-Type` before any write/flush to be handled correctly. Also, thanks for the `closeQuietly` and `ResponseEntity` tips.