# SEC7113: "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch" error using lighttpd and IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an web application calle `myapp` running on a lighttpd server developed using PHP.

Both Chrome as Firefox displays  correctly my page, as well as Edge. But whe I use IE11 it simply does not render the page stylesheet (css). Looking at the debug window (F12) it loads the CSS files with `text/html` type instead of `type/css`, what causes IE11 to complain.

IE11 complains using the **SEC7113** Error: **"CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch"**

There are several posts on SO related to SEC7113 error using Internet Explorer, but none of them was able to solve my problem.

My environment data:

I have `lighttpd` installed as a web server. My `lighttpd.conf` configuration file:

```
    server.modules += (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_setenv",
    "mod_fastcgi"
)

server.document-root        = "/usr/local/sbin/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/usr/local/sbin/www/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd_error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"

server.max-request-size = 2097152
server.network-backend = "writev"

#
# Redirect to public folder
#
url.redirect = ("^/$" => "/myapp/public" )


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

#
# PHP CGI Configuration
#
fastcgi.server = (".php" => ((
                        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket", 
            "bin-environment" => (
                "PATH" => env.PATH,
                "MYAPP_HOME" => env.MYAPP_HOME,
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            )
        ))
    )

#
# Set environment variables
#
setenv.add-environment = ("PATH" => env.PATH,
                         "MYAPP_HOME" => env.MYAPP_HOME,
                         "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH
                        )

#
# Rewrite rules
#
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
               "^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$" => "/myapp/public/index.php?url=$1&extension=$2",
               "^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\??(.+)?$" => "/myapp/public/index.php?url=$1&$2")


#
# Mimetype assign
#
mimetype.assign += (  ".html" => "text/html",
                     ".txt" => "text/plain",
                     ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
                     ".png" => "image/png",
                     ".css" => "text/css",
                     ".js" =>  "text/javascript"
                   )
```

The HTML page that I´m loading (dynamically built using PHP):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>Traansit AEI RTU</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    </head>

    <span><base href="/myapp/public/"><!-- [if lte IE 6]></base><![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/traansit.bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
</span>

    <body>



            <base href=/myapp/public/>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <br />

        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <img src="img/my_logo_sm.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
            <h3>MYAPP</h3>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="dialogDiv"></div>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="height: 470px">

            <h4>MY APPLICATION</h4>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">


        <div class="jumbotron" style="height: 470px">

        <h4>Logon:</h4>
            <br />

        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username:</label> 
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username">
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label> 
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="login">Submit</button>
            </div> 

        </form>

    </div>

</div>




        </div>

        <footer></footer>


    </body>
</html>
```

Finally I´ve checked my registry database and found that my `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.css ContentType ="text/css"`

I don´t know if the problem is on the lighttpd server that is not sending the correct type of in the HTML page that is not setting correctly the page type.

Help appreciated.

**OBS:**

As Graham pointed out, this is a know problem with IE1

- 1 (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226863/ie9-standard-view-no-load-css/8227789#8227789)). My problem is how to solve it as none of the
  proposed solutions are working.
- I´m using IE in my laptop connected to the lighttpd server on a Linux
  machine on my local network. So, I´m accessing the page remotely.

Comment: There was an issue with IE9 and CSS mime types back a few years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226863/ie9-standard-view-no-load-css/8227789#8227789

Comment: Yes, I´m aware of this. This is the exactly the problem that is happening, but I cannot find a way to solve it on my environment even reading all posts related to it.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but your HTML has an error that causes the links for the stylesheets to end up in the body.

Comment: What file type does the stylesheet have if you load it directly into the browser?

Comment: I can´t load it directly on the browser. My browser is in the network and I cannot access individual files from my lighttpd server.